# Extend $(A^{(1)}_1\times A^{(1)}_2)\cap(A^{(2)}_1\times A^{(2)}_2)=(A^{(1)}_1\cap A^{(2)}_1)\times(A^{(1)}_2\cap A^{(2)}_2)$

Tags: measure-theory

My question arises by reading through the *Probability For Statisticians*.

> Definition 1.1 (Product spaces) Suppose $(\Omega, \mathcal{A})$ and $\left(\Omega^{\prime}, \mathcal{A}^{\prime}\right)$ are measurable spaces. Denote
> $$
> \mathcal{F}_{0} \equiv\left\{A \times A^{\prime}: A \in \mathcal{A} \text { and } A^{\prime} \in \mathcal{A}^{\prime}\right\}
> $$
> where
> $$
> A \times A^{\prime} \equiv\left\{\left(\omega, \omega^{\prime}\right): \omega \in A, \omega^{\prime} \in A^{\prime}\right\}
> $$
> is called a measurable rectangle. The sets $A \times \Omega^{\prime}$ and $\Omega \times A^{\prime}$ are called cylinder sets. Define
> $$
> \mathcal{F} \equiv\left\{\sum_{i=1}^{m} A_{i} \times A_{i}^{\prime}: m \geq 1, A_{i} \in \mathcal{A} \text { and } A_{i}^{\prime} \in \mathcal{A}^{\prime}\right\}
> $$

The book claims that $\mathcal{F}$  is a field. However, it is a bit weird because $\mathcal{F_0}$ is a $\sigma$-field. Can the class of sum of elements from a $\sigma$-field ends up being up to a field? I know that:

$(A^{(1)}_1\times A^{(1)}_2)\cap(A^{(2)}_1\times A^{(2)}_2)=(A^{(1)}_1\cap A^{(2)}_1)\times(A^{(1)}_2\cap A^{(2)}_2)$

because $(\omega_1,\omega_2)\in(A^{(1)}_1\times A^{(1)}_2)\cap(A^{(2)}_1\times A^{(2)}_2) \\
\Leftrightarrow (\omega_1,\omega_2)\in (A^{(1)}_1\times A^{(1)}_2)\text{ and }(A^{(2)}_1\times A^{(2)}_2) \\
\Leftrightarrow \omega_1\in(A^{(1)}_1\cap A^{(2)}_1),\omega_2\in(A^{(1)}_2\cap A^{(2)}_2)\\
\Leftrightarrow (\omega_1,\omega_2)\in (A^{(1)}_1\cap A^{(2)}_1)\times(A^{(1)}_2\cap A^{(2)}_2)$

Suppose $$\bigcap^k(A^{(n)}_1\times A^{(n)}_2)=(\bigcap^k A^{(n)}_1)\times(\bigcap^k A^{(n)}_2)$$ is true, it seems
$$\bigcap^{k+1}(A^{(n)}_1\times A^{(n)}_2)\\
=[(\bigcap^k A^{(n)}_1)\times(\bigcap^k A^{(n)}_2)]\bigcap(A_1^{(k+1)}\times A_2^{(k+1)})\\
=(\bigcap^{k+1} A^{(n)}_1)\times(\bigcap^{k+1} A^{(n)}_2)$$
is  also true, therefore by induction
$$\bigcap^\infty(A^{(n)}_1\times A^{(n)}_2)=(\bigcap^\infty A^{(n)}_1)\times(\bigcap^\infty A^{(n)}_2)$$

I know if $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{A'}$ is semi-algebra, $\mathcal{F}$ must be a field, but in this case, I feel $\mathcal{F}$ should be a $\sigma$-algebra instead of just being an algebra. I think if this equality is correct, I should be able to show $\mathcal{F}$ is indeed a $\sigma$-field. Am I correct in my reasoning? If I am wrong, where have I made mistakes?

Comment: $\mathcal{F}_{0}$ is not a $\sigma$-field. It is not even a field. The union of two measurable rectangles may not be a measurable rectangle. Also, the complement of a measurable rectangle may not be a measurable rectangle. 
Even if $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{A}^{\prime}$ are $\sigma$-fields,  $\mathcal{F}_{0}$ is just a semi-algebra. Your mistake is that you are just focusing "intersections", but you need to consider how those classes behave under "unions" (and complements).

Comment: @Ramiro Hi, thank you for making the comment! I thought about the compliment, actually, since $(A\times A')^c=A\times A'^c+A^c\times A'+A^c\times A'^c$, I presumably thought that the union of these three components should also be in $\mathcal{F}$ , clearly I shouldn't have made this assumption.