# Why $ \mathcal{F}_{0} \equiv\{A \times A': A \in \mathcal{A} \text { and } A' \in \mathcal{A}\} $ is not a $\sigma$-field?

Tags: measure-theory

I asked a related question yesterday:[Extend $(A^{(1)}_1\times A^{(1)}_2)\cap(A^{(2)}_1\times A^{(2)}_2)=(A^{(1)}_1\cap A^{(2)}_1)\times(A^{(1)}_2\cap A^{(2)}_2)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3942457/extend-a1-1-times-a1-2-capa2-1-times-a2-2-a1-1-ca) where I am confused and think

$$
\mathcal{F}_{0} \equiv\left\{A \times A^{\prime}: A \in \mathcal{A} \text { and } A^{\prime} \in \mathcal{A}^{\prime}\right\}
$$

should be a $\mathcal{F_0}$ is a $\sigma$-field,  if both $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{A'}$ are $\sigma-$field. My reasoning can be found in the link I attached but I was told this supposition is wrong because this class of set is not closed under countable unions.

I am very confused by intuition if both $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{A'}$ are $\sigma$-field, how can the collection of all product of sets end up not closed under union? I proved why the product is closed under intersection in the link provided which I hope is not wrong. But on the textbook I used, it didn't provide me with the formula for the union. Can someone provide some counter examples to show that $\mathcal{F_0}$ is not a $\sigma-$field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider $\mathcal{F}_{0} \equiv\left\{A \times A^{\prime}: A \in \mathcal{A} \text { and } A^{\prime} \in \mathcal{A}^{\prime}\right\}$.
The complement of an element of $\mathcal{F}_0$ need not be an element of $\mathcal{F}_0$.  The union of two elements of $\mathcal{F}_0$ need not be an element of $\mathcal{F}_0$.  Intersection is OK, however.

Surely you can work out a counterexample for the complement using the two-element set $\Omega = \{0,1\}$ with $A = A' = \{0\}$.

Answer (score 3):

$\mathcal F_0$ isn't even closed under *finite* unions.  For example, let $\mathcal A$ and $\mathcal A'$ both be the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb{R}$.  Then $(0,1) \times (0,1)$ and $(1,2) \times (1,2)$ are both in $\mathcal F_0$, but $((0,1) \times (0,1)) \cup ((1,2) \times (1,2))$ is not a product of any two subsets of $\mathbb{R}$.